# Block function when state is not equal to false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, if-statement

I have small problem with my Tic-tac-toe app.  When I'm playing against AI (computer) and when I win, computer makes another move and it is not supposed to happen. I just want to block this function, so I can prevent this problem. It sounds easy but I swear to god, I've tried everything and nothing blocks that function.

When you start the app, you have 2 options. Player vs player and player vs computer. Choose player vs. computer..

Game will start and you are the first player on draw. After you click, **computerMove()** will be fired and computer will randomly pick empty column a insert there it's mark (O). Problem is when you win, computer doesn't stop and pick another one.

I've tried to prevent it like this

**in checkWinner function, which is called after every click**

```
      if(xCount === 3){
        setWinner('X WINS!');
        displayWinner();
        setWinnerCount(prevState => ({
          ...prevState,
          player1:prevState.player1 + 1
        }));

        setPlayerVsPlayer({
          AI:false,
          AImove
        })
        return;
      }
```

if xCount of oCount == 3, winner state is set from false to 'X wins!' ,'O wins!' or 'Draw!' .. depends on who is the winner.

**Or in computerMove function**

```
if (emptyCols.length > 0 && winner === false) {
   //run whole computer move function .. i.e. pick random column and insert here O, etc..
}
```

So logically, If I win, computer shouldn't be able to make one more move because winner state is not false but it's value is 'X Wins!'..

Can you please someone look at it? I don't really know how to prevent this...

https://codesandbox.io/s/cold-shape-xg7l7?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because the 'setWinner' function is asynchronous and the 'if' statement is executed before the value of 'winner' gets updated. So when the 'if' condition is checked, the value of winner is still false and therefore the computer makes its move.

You can use the 'useEffect' method provided by the react and place your 'if' statement in that function to obtain the desired behaviour. Or you can make the 'setWinner' function synchronous using async-await and promises.

Comment: Thank you for you answer ! I will be back on work in few minutes and will try it out . Do you have time if It doesnt work so you can take a look at it ,please ?

Comment: I have added this but it did the same thing..   useEffect(()=>{
if(winner !== false){
setPlayerVsPlayer({
AI:false,
  AImove:false
})
}
},[winner])

Comment: You can also check out this article- https://sung.codes/blog/2018/12/07/setting-react-hooks-states-in-a-sync-like-manner/

Comment: Read the article, if you still don't get it then i will do it.

Comment: I dont get it . If i try to add useEffect to checkwinner function it throws an error that useEffect can not be storied inside the function and when i put it out like i have showed you few comments higher ,it did nothing . Sorry but im not that skilled in react :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223711/discussion-between-pinncik-and-naveen-kumar).

Comment: I give up.. 2 hours trying to fix that, adding new states or conditions and nothing helps.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, also I’ve accepted your answer . Can i have one more question? Do you have any experience with animating react-router-dom routes with react-spring?

Comment: Sorry i have no experience with that.